# Module.exports not finding function

Tags: node.js

So I am creating a basic user login system (this is one of my first nodejs projects) and I am wanting to redirect the user to the 'dashboard' page with a successful login.

First of all I am not sure this is the best way to do the redirecting so I am open to suggestions.

The problem I am having is after calling the function and the user logs in I want to call this function:

```
var loginResponse = () =>{
  io.emit('loginResponse');
}
```

This is in the server.js file (the main server file) and I am exporting it like so

```
module.exports = {
  loginResponse : loginResponse
};
```

I am then after all the validation, calling db etc. is done wanting to call it in the login.js file as shown:

```
var createUserSession = (userSessionObj) =>{
  session.user = userSessionObj;
  serverMain.loginResponse();
};
```

I am requiring the file server file like so:

```
const serverMain = require('../server');
```

However, I am getting the following error on execute:

```
(node:35012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: serverMain.loginResponse is not a function
    at createUserSession (/Users/chrisholder/Documents/Programming/RandomPrograms/registerlogin/server/registrationlogin/login.js:83:14)
    at hashing.comparePassword.then (/Users/chrisholder/Documents/Programming/RandomPrograms/registerlogin/server/registrationlogin/login.js:73:7)
    at <anonymous>
(node:35012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:35012) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried using the 'path' module as another way to requiring the server.js file however, it has not worked.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you import the `loginResponse` function directly with something like `const {loginResponse} = require('../server)`?

Comment: I just tried this and it is giving me the same error unfortunately

Comment: If you change the content of the `loginResponse` function to something simple (like `console.log('Hello');`), do you still get the same error? Perhaps it has something to do with `io.emit`.

Comment: Tried it, it gives the same error